# Passing class by reference doesn't change original

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that handles rendering sprites, which has a `Ball` and `Gun` objects on it, sets their sprites, and renders them every frame. I want to pass in that ball object to gun, so that gun can fire when a user presses space (input is handled on gun). I tried pointers, and now passing by reference, but when I change it after passing it in it doesn't affect the original. In my main class I call gun.init(&ball) that I'll show here. `Gun` has a variable `Ball mBall`.

```
class Gun : public GameObj
{
public:
    Gun()
        :GameObj(), mWaitSecs(0)
    {}
    void Update();      
  void Init(Ball &ball);      //init function that passes in ball?
private:
    float mWaitSecs;    //delay after firing beforeo you can move/fire
    Ball mBall;
};

void Gun::Init(Ball &ball) {  
  mBall = ball;
}
```

Comment: You'd need your member variable to be `Ball* mBall` then in `Init` you'd do `mBall = &ball;`. However then you'd have to ensure that the `Ball` lifetime is longer than your `Gun` object so you don't have a dangling pointer.

Comment: I see you are doing a `Ball` copy assignment. Does the `Ball` class follow the rule of 3?

Comment: Pleae provide a [mcve]

Comment: @CoryKramer I changed it to pointers. I can't do mBall = &ball because it's a Ball* not a Ball. but it still acts the same. I've put breakpoints and it is running through the code but not changing balls position after being passed in. in original class I pass it. mGun.Init(&mBall), everything is as it should be as far as I'm aware

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 it's just this code, then in my other class I have a Ball and Gun as member variables. in the other class I call gunmember.Init(&ballmember);

Comment: @L.Birkett the problem may be in your other code. How are you creating and passing ball? Are you using `Ball b`, `Ball * b = new Ball()`, etc.? Create for us a single, runnable file with a `main()` that demonstrates the problem, not just snippets of code that are missing context.

Comment: i wrote an answer and I honestly hope it helps but still I would like to remind you that there is no good excuse for not posting a [mcve]. The code you posted could be correct in a different context. If you show only pieces of code it is always possible to invent other code that would make yours correct (ie with a proper implementation of `Ball` you could get what you want without changing a bit on the code you posted). Please dont let us guess. cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

> [..]  but when I change it after passing it in it doesn't affect the original.

Frankly, you have a basic misunderstanding. And to clear that up, I have to take a small detour.

**Pass by value**

```
void foo_value(int x) { x += 42; }
```

calling this function via

```
int y = 50;
foo_value(y);
```

will not change the value of `y`.

**Pass by reference**

```
void foo_ref(int& x) { x += 42; }
```

calling this function will modify `y`:

```
int y = 50;
foo_ref(y); 
assert(y == 50+42);
```

**Rebinding references**

You cannot rebind references. That's why you cannot not initialize a reference:

```
int& y;      // error
int x;
int& y = x;  // ok
```

Once you have a reference you cannot make it refer to something else. You cannot "reassign" the reference:

```
int x = 0;
int& ref = x;
int y = 42;
ref = y;          // same as x = y;
```

after the last line, `ref` is still a reference to `x`.

**Your code**

You do pass `ball` by reference, but your member `mBall` is not a reference. `mBall` is a copy of the ball refered to by `ball`. An example similar to your code is

```
void foo_copy_from_ref(int& x) {
    int mx = x;
    mx = 42;
}
```

Modifying a copy has no effect on the original, no matter if you made the copy from a reference.

You can have a reference to a `Ball` as member, but you have to initialize it in the constructor and you cannot make it refer to a different `Ball` later.

Comment: *and you cannot make it refer to a different `Ball` later.* And if you need to, use raw pointer as observer.